# docker-compose not printing stdout in Python app

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

When using a `print()` statement in a Python app running inside a Docker container that's managed by Docker Compose, only `sys.stderr` output is logged. Vanilla `print()` statements aren't seen, so this:

```
print("Hello? Anyone there?")
```

... never shows up in the regular logs:

[image]

(You can see other logs explicitly printed by other libs in my app, but none of my own calls.)

How can I avoid my `print()` calls being ignored?

Answer (score 122):

By default, Python buffers output to `sys.stdout`.

There are a few options:

**1. Call an explicit `flush`**

Refactor the original print statement to include a `flush=True` keyword, like:

```
print("Hello? Anyone there?", flush=True)
```

Note: This will cause the *entire* buffer to flush, not just the same print call. So if there are 'bare' print function calls elsewhere (i.e. without `flush=True`) that weren't explicitly unbuffered, these will always be flushed too.

You could achieve the same thing with:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

This option is useful if you want the most control of *when* the flushing will occur.

**2. Unbuffer the entire app via the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` env var**

Drop the following into the `environment` section of your `docker-compose.yml` file:

`PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1`

This will cause all output to `stdout` to be flushed immediately.

**3. Run python with `-u`**

Like option #2 above, this will cause Python to run 'unbuffered' across the full execution lifetime of your app. Just run with `python -u <entrypoint.py>` - no need for the environment variable.

Comment: Only  flush=True works. Windows 10, docker-desktop, Python 3.7

Comment: @TDiddy - it worked on July 16th, 2018 when I wrote this. I make no guarantees for the future.

Comment: Running an ap in docker had the impression the app was not running... Upon reviewing the other server logs, we saw connections coming... So the problem was mostly the buffer... This is awesome! Thank you!

Comment: for the second solution, seems to be, that docker changed the syntax for environment variables.          ``` - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1``` worked for me

Comment: It still works. I'm using docker desktop for mac and Python 3.10. Btw, it saved me hours of debugging, thank you

Comment: Setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in `docker-compose.yml` still works

Answer (score 36):

Simple, if you add the option -u in the line of the Dockerfile it will print your logs:

```
CMD ["python", "-u", "my_python_script.py"]
```

No need of changing an environment variable or change all the prints statements of your program.

Comment: `-y` is an invalid flag. `-u` is the correct one (I'l add that to my answer above.)

Comment: does not work Python 3.7, windows 10, docker-desktop

Comment: this solution worked fine for me for    
`FROM python:alpine3.17`

Comment: The -u flag worked for me on docker-compose on macOS. Surprisingly the stdout.flush() approach did not work.

Answer (score 6):

Using `pytest`, the solution for me was to add the `-s` option.

For example, in my scenario where I also needed verbose mode on, I had to put `pytest -sv`.