# docker-compose up stucks on attaching to when running an python scheduler script

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, apscheduler

I have a simple python application to run some scheduled jobs.
I want these jobs to run non-stop as an script.

```
import os
import time
import requests

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from pytz import utc

def a_get_request_to_api():
    request.get("some_url")

def another_get_request_to_api():
    try:    
        request.get("some_url")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('STARTING SCHEDULER ...')

    # initialize Blocking Scheduler
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone=utc)

    # add jobs to run on scheduled time
    scheduler.add_job(a_get_request_to_api, trigger='interval', hours=1, max_instances=2)
    scheduler.add_job(another_get_request_to_api, trigger='interval', hours=6, max_instances=2)



    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        scheduler.start()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit) as e:
        print(e)
```

this is fine and works when i run directly from terminal.

my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install requests apscheduler pytz
CMD [ "python", "scheduler.py" ]
```

and a simple `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  scheduler:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

But when i dockerize the app and `docker-compose up` it stucks at `attaching to`

Comment: did you copy the "scheduler.py" file into the container? if not, use COPY command to do so

Comment: I volumed the directory containing `scheduler.py` in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Please try adding the following just to pinpoint the problem:
in DOCKERFILE:
COPY scheduler.py /app
ENTRYPOINT python application.py .
and in docker-compose:
build: ./app

Comment: I added the `-u` flag to the Dockerfile `CMD ["python", "-u", "scheduler.py"]` and now it is working. I think it's related to python buffers the `sys.stdout`. as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362213/docker-compose-not-printing-stdout-in-python-app

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try running docker-compose in detach mode :

```
docker-compose up -d

-d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                           print new container names. Incompatible with
                           --abort-on-container-exit.
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: I dont see how that would help considering its not even getting to his code (thus not getting to the print statement)

Comment: I think it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362213/docker-compose-not-printing-stdout-in-python-app