# docker-compose hangs after attaching

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose, it just hangs.  The first line of my code is a print statement and I'm not seeing any output.
docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  grip-sim-results-parser:
    container_name: grip-sim-results-parser
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM library/python:3.7-stretch
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y vim
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org -r /requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

docker-compose version

```
user@ubuntu:~/projects/grip/grip-sim-results-parser$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe
```

Docker version

```
user@ubuntu:~/projects/grip/grip-sim-results-parser$ docker --version
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
```

Linux version

```
user@ubuntu:~/projects/grip/grip-sim-results-parser$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.13.0-46-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 12 12:36:29 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

app.py

```
....
def main():
    print('main')
```

docker-compose output

```
user@ubuntu:~/projects/grip/grip-sim-results-parser$ docker-compose --verbose up --build
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/user/.docker/config.json', '/home/user/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: /home/user/.docker/config.json
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'auths' section
docker.auth.parse_auth: Found entry (registry='https://index.docker.io/v1/', username='jcald1')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/version HTTP/1.1" 200 543
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localhost
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': ''}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '18.06.1-ce', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.38', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2018-08-21T17:23:27.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': 'e68fc7a', 'GoVersion': 'go1.10.3', 'KernelVersion': '4.13.0-46-generic', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}], Version=18.06.1-ce, ApiVersion=1.38, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=e68fc7a, GoVersion=go1.10.3, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.13.0-46-generic, BuildTime=2018-08-21T17:23:27.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('gripsimresultsparser_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/networks/gripsimresultsparser_default HTTP/1.1" 404 61
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info <- ()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/info HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info -> {'Architecture': 'x86_64',
 'BridgeNfIp6tables': True,
 'BridgeNfIptables': True,
 'CPUSet': True,
 'CPUShares': True,
 'CgroupDriver': 'cgroupfs',
 'ClusterAdvertise': '',
 'ClusterStore': '',
 'ContainerdCommit': {'Expected': '468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e',
                      'ID': '468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e'},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('grip-sim-results-parser_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/networks/grip-sim-results-parser_default HTTP/1.1" 200 590
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {'Attachable': True,
 'ConfigFrom': {'Network': ''},
 'ConfigOnly': False,
 'Containers': {},
 'Created': '2018-10-02T22:17:49.401421224-04:00',
 'Driver': 'bridge',
 'EnableIPv6': False,
 'IPAM': {'Config': [{'Gateway': '172.27.0.1', 'Subnet': '172.27.0.0/16'}],
          'Driver': 'default',
          'Options': None},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-sim-results-parser', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-sim-results-parser%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=gripsimresultsparser', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgripsimresultsparser%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-sim-results-parser', 'com.docker.compose.service=grip-sim-results-parser', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-sim-results-parser%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dgrip-sim-results-parser%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1133
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['app.py'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['python3', 'app.py'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
compose.service.build: Building grip-sim-results-parser
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (path='/home/user/grip-sim-results-parser', tag='grip-sim-results-parser_grip-sim-results-parser', rm=True, forcerm=False, pull=False, nocache=False, dockerfile=None, cache_from=None, labels=None, buildargs={}, network_mode=None, target=None, shmsize=None, extra_hosts=None, container_limits={'memory': None}, gzip=False, isolation=None, platform=None)
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Looking for auth config
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Sending auth config ('https://index.docker.io/v1/')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/build?t=grip-sim-results-parser_grip-sim-results-parser&q=False&nocache=False&rm=True&forcerm=False&pull=False HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build -> <generator object APIClient._stream_helper at 0x7f5717d10a98>
Step 1/8 : FROM library/python:3.7-stretch
 ---> a9d071760c82
Step 2/8 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 75cc76eecf8a
Step 3/8 : RUN apt-get install -y vim
 ---> Using cache
 ---> af651ad63dda
Step 4/8 : ADD . /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5ae41ae91671
Step 5/8 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a709b10facf8
Step 6/8 : COPY requirements.txt /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d1a13239b96
Step 7/8 : RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org -r /requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7e6d00d828ae
Step 8/8 : CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a2bdd386cd1
Successfully built 1a2bdd386cd1
Successfully tagged grip-sim-results-parser_grip-sim-results-parser:latest
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker close <- ()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker close -> None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-sim-results-parser', 'com.docker.compose.service=grip-sim-results-parser', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-sim-results-parser%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dgrip-sim-results-parser%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1133
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('grip-sim-results-parser_grip-sim-results-parser')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/images/grip-sim-results-parser_grip-sim-results-parser/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['python3', 'app.py'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['app.py'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['python3', 'app.py'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
            'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Service: grip-sim-results-parser>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: grip-sim-results-parser>
Starting grip-sim-results-parser ... 
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Container: grip-sim-results-parser (1f8f0b)>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Container: grip-sim-results-parser (1f8f0b)>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach <- ('1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68', stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1 HTTP/1.1" 101 0
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x7f5717d32908>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start <- ('1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/1f8f0b4c36a90c4771e7a2373986dcaed61dbfd140c66b5840bf310edd0c0e68/start HTTP/1.1" 204 0
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start -> None
Starting grip-sim-results-parser ... done
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: grip-sim-results-parser>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
Attaching to grip-sim-results-parser
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-sim-results-parser', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-sim-results-parser%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x7f5717ce9cc0>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see output from python, try adding following lines to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
grip-sim-results-parser:
  environment:
    - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

Comment: Thanks.  The underlying error went away on its own, but this is good to know.

Comment: I was having a similar issue, in my version, `while True: print('main')` worked just fine but if I added `time.sleep(...)` after the `print` statement then nothing would be printed out. Adding `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to the environment solved the issue, however, it would be great to know the reason behind it.

Comment: Python buffers stdout by default which keeps the output from being printed. This is why if you restart the container you might see all the output show up at once. https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

Comment: Other options are listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362213/docker-compose-not-printing-stdout-in-python-app/51362214#51362214