# sending file to host on update from inside docker container

Tags: python, bash, docker, logging

my python program in a docker container updates a log file. Every time this happens, I want this file to be copied to host.
My folder structure is like that:

```
Dockerfile
my_program
   \___ log
         \__ my_log.log
   \___ run_my_program.py
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
# start miniconda base image
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# copy main files
COPY my_program ./

# copy conda environment instructions and install it
COPY conda_env.yml ./
RUN conda env create --name my_env --file conda_env.yml

# output port
EXPOSE 8050

# run LipViz and cast it to exposed port
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "my_env", "python", "-u", "run_my_program.py", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8050"]

# copy the log file from inside the container outside of it, every time it is changed
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y inotify-tools
CMD ["sh", "-c", "while true; do inotifywait -e modify /log/my_log.log -m && docker cp $(docker ps -q):/log/my_log.log .; done"]
```

When running the `docker cp` command alone, it works (and the log files are updated correctly). However the update detection does not seem to work so far.

/EDIT: As mentioned by last comment: a better way is to bind-mount my log file like so:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/my_log.log:/log/my_log.log -p 8050:8050 my_program
```

Comment: You can't run `docker cp` from inside a Docker container unless you have exposed the Docker socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) inside the container. A better option would be to bind-mount a host directory into the container, and then just place your log file in the mountpoint. Then you don't need to copy anything and you don't need your `inotifywait` loop.

Comment: Apart from the volume, I'd propose simply writing to stdout. You can then retrieve that output using `docker logs`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This would be another option, if I would not be also struggling with this unsolved problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362213/docker-compose-not-printing-stdout-in-python-app